# Change seller's name on Appstore

Tags: ios, iphone

Is there anyway with my developer program to change the name that appears under my application name?

A picture is like a thousand words so...

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Contact Apple**

The easiest way to change your seller name is to contact Apple developer support. If there is a typo or inaccuracy in your seller name they should be willing to change it. Back before I released Card Share my individual account had a seller name for a fictitious entity that did not exist. Since it wasn’t my legal name, Apple support was willing to make the name change. I contacted support and within 24 hours my seller name was changed and updated in the App Store.
Here is the email to contact Apple about seller name changes and other iTunes related support: *itunesconnect@apple.com*

**New Account + App Transfer**

Outside of contacting Apple, there is a more hands-on approach. Before WWDC in 2013, Apple announced the ability to transfer apps between developer accounts. By creating a new developer account with a new name and transferring your apps to that account, you can effectively change your seller name. There are a few restrictions on apps that can be transferred.

**[Reference](http://www.brynbodayle.com/changing-app-store-seller-name/)**

Comment: thank you very much for your answer.
One question more if i want to change it to be the same as the app yyou believe the will change it?

Comment: @mikevorisis No, they will not let you put the app's name as the distributor's name. You have to provide some papers of your Company so it can change. But generally they dont change the name as you want. It has to be a physical person or a registered Company. Read the guidelines.